# WordPress 3.1 Install Error

Tags: installation

I'm trying to run a fresh install on my server with WP 3.1. Problem is I'm getting errors after setting up the config. (attached image)

I've installed the previous versions of WP before and have had no trouble.

```
nction weblog_ping($server = '', $path = '') { global $wp_version; include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-IXR.php'); include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-http-ixr-client.php'); // using a timeout of 3 seconds should be enough to cover slow servers $client = new WP_HTTP_IXR_Client($server, ((!strlen(trim($path)) || ('/' == $path)) ? false : $path)); $client->timeout = 3; $client->useragent .= ' -- WordPress/'.$wp_version; // when set to true, this outputs debug messages by itself $client->debug = false; $home = trailingslashit( home_url() ); if ( !$client->query('weblogUpdates.extendedPing', get_option('blogname'), $home, get_bloginfo('rss2_url') ) ) // then try a normal ping $client->query('weblogUpdates.ping', get_option('blogname'), $home); } // // Cache // /** * Removes comment ID from the comment cache. * * @since 2.3.0 * @package WordPress * @subpackage Cache * * @param int|array $ids Comment ID or array of comment IDs to remove from cache */ function clean_comment_cache($ids) { foreach ( (array) $ids as $id ) wp_cache_delete($id, 'comment'); wp_cache_set('last_changed', time(), 'comment'); } /** * Updates the comment cache of given comments. * * Will add the comments in $comments to the cache. If comment ID already exists * in the comment cache then it will not be updated. The comment is added to the * cache using the comment group with the key using the ID of the comments. * * @since 2.3.0 * @package WordPress * @subpackage Cache * * @param array $comments Array of comment row objects */ function update_comment_cache($comments) { foreach ( (array) $comments as $comment ) wp_cache_add($comment->comment_ID, $comment, 'comment'); } // // Internal // /** * Close comments on old posts on the fly, without any extra DB queries. Hooked to the_posts. * * @access private * @since 2.7.0 * * @param object $posts Post data object. * @return object */ function _close_comments_for_old_posts( $posts ) { if ( empty($posts) || !is_singular() || !get_option('close_comments_for_old_posts') ) return $posts; $days_old = (int) get_option('close_comments_days_old'); if ( !$days_old ) return $posts; if ( time() - strtotime( $posts[0]->post_date_gmt ) > ( $days_old * 24 * 60 * 60 ) ) { $posts[0]->comment_status = 'closed'; $posts[0]->ping_status = 'closed'; } return $posts; } /** * Close comments on an old post. Hooked to comments_open and pings_open. * * @access private * @since 2.7.0 * * @param bool $open Comments open or closed * @param int $post_id Post ID * @return bool $open */ function _close_comments_for_old_post( $open, $post_id ) { if ( ! $open ) return $open; if ( !get_option('close_comments_for_old_posts') ) return $open; $days_old = (int) get_option('close_comments_days_old'); if ( !$days_old ) return $open; $post = get_post($post_id); if ( time() - strtotime( $post->post_date_gmt ) > ( $days_old * 24 * 60 * 60 ) ) return false; return $open; } ?>
```

Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argumented is expected to be a valid callback, 'sanitize_comment_cookies' was given in /nfs/c05/h01/mnt/71351/domains/kasildenim.com/html/test/dev/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 395

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /wp-includes/comment.php:9) in wp-admin/install.php on line 54

Answer (score 1):

It looks like one of the files is incomplete. Try copying all files over again.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, all you need to do is to find in the first few lines of your `function.php` file and see if there is any commenting formatted as `<!--your comment-->` OUTSIDE of the `<?php` tag. It could cause the problem as I solved mine after remove the comment and move the comment at that begining of the `function.php` file into the `<?php` tag and use `//` instead.